# How to count and display with specific column and related data

Tags: sql-server

i need SQL query to generate the below second data output from the below first data. please help me .................

```
    ----------
    Oracle        Date         col1               col2               col3      Office           Route

    ----------

    8940        4/23/2014 11:33            8               IT         A         LEG           LR1
    ----------
    5454        4/23/2014 11:33            8               CCA                B        LEG    LR1 

    ----------
    1717        4/23/2014 11:33            8               CCA                A         HQ    LR1  

    ----------

and i need the output


----------
Route          NO.Of Id  per  Route  Office  date

----------

LR1            3                  LEG          4/23/2014 11:33
----------

LR1            1                  HQ           4/23/2014 11:33
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

what should be the "NO.Of" ??
you write a "3" in the first record of result ... 
are "Id" and "per" 2 columns - if yes, why empty ? (they are not in the source)
why you have only 2 records in result out of 3 in table

Comment: thank you very much! in my table i have columns(oracleid,route,office,date) and what i need is  number of occurrence of oracleid's per one rout with corresponding office

Comment: try this: SELECT Count(*) as OracleID, route, office FROM table GROUP BY route, office - The more fields you add, the more it can diverse, as different values in one column will not be grouped (of course ...)

Comment: Thank you again.for this <<SELECT Count(*) as OracleID, route, office FROM table GROUP BY route, office>> it works and perfect but when one column added it doesnot work for example <<SELECT Count(*) as OracleID, route, office,date FROM viewfleet GROUP BY route, office,date>>

Comment: well, i assume that in the "date" field, you have always another value as your shown sample indicates date AND time. i further assume, that there are also seconds in it, looks like a timestamp.
Grouping ONLY takes the exact same value together, if you have "4/23/2014 11:33:00" and "4/23/2014 11:33:01" this is not the same and cannot be grouped ...

Comment: thank you very much ,know i got solution by following your direction by converting datetime to date like this<< select routename as RouteName,count(routename) as NumberOfEmployee,OfficeLocationName,CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,Createddate))) from viewfleet group by routename,OfficeLocationName,CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,Createddate)));>>